# Automatic twitter posts when uploading a video by API on youtube are always in english

Tags: twitter, youtube-api

I'm using .net library to upload video on Youtube by API. I linked the twitter account to tweet new videos added on playlists. Everything works but the tweet is in english: "I added a video to a @YouTube playlist...".
If I upload it directly by youtube site I get the message in my country language: "Ho aggiunto un video...".
Is there a way to tell API I want a specific language?
Thanks.